# C#, SQLite - Calculate each cells value and put in another cells of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to apply formula `(Basic_Salary/MonthDays)*Workingdays` and put its result in `Final Amount`:

[image: this is my datagridview1 in which data fetch from sqlite database]
Here is my code but when I run program it shows:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.SelectedCells[dataGridView1.Columns["Final_Amount"].Index].Value = 
            Convert.ToDouble(row.SelectedCells[dataGridView1.Columns["Basic_Salary"].Index].Value) * 
            Convert.ToDouble(row.SelectedCells[dataGridView1.Columns["WorkingDays"].Index].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `foreach` use a simple `for` then access it like `dataGrid.Rows[row].Cells[colIndex].Value` -HTH ;).

Comment: you want to generate all its final total? or only the cell where the user leave? hmm. if you want to generate all its final total then try to revise your code. `foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells["FinalTotal"].Value =          Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Basic_Salary"].Value) *             Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["WorkingDays"].Value);
    }`

Comment: Thanks but when I try to convert cell in to int or anything it show could not cast object value to int

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Instead of doing those inside `CellLeave` event doing them after clicking a button like <kbd>Calculate</kbd>.

A working code can be something like this:

Data:

```
+--+--------------+-------------+---------+--------+
|..| Basic_Salary | WorkingDays | monthNo | YearNo |
+--+--------------+-------------+---------+--------+
|..|        12000 |          20 |       1 |   2017 |
|..|        12000 |          20 |       3 |   2017 |
|..|        13000 |          22 |       2 |   2017 |
|..|        13000 |          21 |       4 |   2017 |
+--+--------------+-------------+---------+--------+
```

Code:

```
//// use this condition if you don't have that column in your data-source
if (dataGridView.Columns.Contains("Final_Amount") == false)
{
    dataGridView.Columns.Add("Final_Amount", "Final Amount");
}

dataGridView.Refresh();

//// I extract indexes of my needed columns
var colIndexFinalAmount = dataGridView.Columns["Final_Amount"].Index;
//// when you know `DataPropertyName` of the column instead of its name use a way like this
var colIndexBasicSalary = dataGridView.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().SingleOrDefault(w=> w.DataPropertyName == "Basic_Salary").Index;
var colIndexWorkingDays = dataGridView.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.DataPropertyName == "WorkingDays").Index;
var colIndexYearNo = dataGridView.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.DataPropertyName == "YearNo").Index;
var colIndexMonthNo = dataGridView.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.DataPropertyName == "MonthNo").Index;

//// using a simple for is better in this situation    
for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    //// extract values from your cells but in an expected type (mine is double as my final amount will be double)
    var bs = double.Parse(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[colIndexBasicSalary].Value.ToString());
    var wd = double.Parse(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[colIndexWorkingDays].Value.ToString());
    //// A way of getting days of a month is this:
    var yn = int.Parse(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[colIndexYearNo].Value.ToString());
    var mn = int.Parse(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[colIndexMonthNo].Value.ToString());
    var md = (double)DateTime.DaysInMonth(yn, mn);

    //// now, just calculate what you want and set it as `Value` like this:
    dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[colIndexFinalAmount].Value = bs / md * wd;
}
```

Result will be:

```
+--+--------------+-------------+---------+--------+------------------+
|..| Basic_Salary | WorkingDays | monthNo | YearNo |   Final Amount   |
+--+--------------+-------------+---------+--------+------------------+
|..|        12000 |          20 |       1 |   2017 | 7741.93548387097 |
|..|        12000 |          20 |       3 |   2017 | 7741.93548387097 |
|..|        13000 |          22 |       2 |   2017 | 10214.2857142857 |
|..|        13000 |          21 |       4 |   2017 | 9100             |
+--+--------------+-------------+---------+--------+------------------+
```